# Make android google maps polyline appear above street names?

Tags: android, google-maps

How to add a polyline to google map in android **above** street/area name?

[image]

Comment: Is that a coding question? I have no experience with google-maps on android, but is this usage of an API or will someone suggest a menue item in an app. Bit at a loss here. Maybe add some detail to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible in an easy way due to how google maps API handles the "background".
If you set the background to normal or hybrid, the map is drawn as a background either in road view like your screenshot or in satellite view if hybrid is selected.
Then all the users features are drawn (and eventually overlays, lines, poligons, then points and lastly, street names. You can't really change this, but you could do a trick:
- Use just the satellite view (so no roads will be added).
- Remove the google background and add an alternative one (there are different services like Open Street Map, Mapnik ecc that allows it).

Following the second choice could also allow to add googlemaps background from web api, but I really don't advice to do it, since you are downloading tiles in a non standard way for google.